# Как рендерить лайки динамично? (MERN)

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, redux-thunk

У меня есть React приложение на MERN.

Логика лайков есть, но они не добавляются динамично. Только после обновления страницы.

Вызывать каждый раз все посты, когда пользователь лайкнул думаю неправильное решение.

Как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант - "свой" лайк записывать в стейт лайков сразу. С некой периодичностью опрашивать сервер и обновлять данные по лайкам того что видно на странице. Т.о. будет видно довольно свежие данные по лайкам.

Comment: Либо делать то же, что описано выше, но на сокетах. Сервер будет хранить данные пользователя, какие посты открыты. Пори обновлении любого из видимых постов, сервер тут же отправит клиенту инфу, что у поста произошли изменения. Тогда не придется дергать сервер со строны клиента. Будет 100 клиентов и они будут долбить сервер по данным

Comment: @SwaD можно просто сообщать на клиента про каждый лайк без наворачивания дополнительной бизнес-логики отслеживания на что он там подписан и что он там открыл и когда этот клиент закрыл страницу

Comment: @nörbörnën Можно и так... Почему бы нет